# Action (button) to open an existing form

Tags: lotus-notes

I have created a view which displays some informations.

Also, on top of view I created an action bar containing 2actions: New entry & Delete entry. There is also a form called 'formmain', where I have some fields & listboxes where I insert the informations that will appear on the view.

What I want to do and I ask for your help: I want when i click the action button 'New entry', the form called 'formmain' will open/be displayed. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the @Compose Formula command for this. Here's an example for your specific form:

```
@Command([Compose]; ""; "formmain")
```

I will recommend that you take a look at the Lotus Domino Designer Help database which is part of your Notes installation. It has a lot of useful information including code examples.

Comment: @FlorinMihalache Keep in mind that creates a new document. If you want to open an existing document, the OpenDocument command or just double-clicking on the document in the view would be the way to go. Similarly, if the user wants to delete a document, they could just click the <kbd>delete</kbd> key instead of your button.